# Possible serial flagging

Tags: discussion, flags, abuse

It looks like someone is systematically going through and flagging dotnetdev's (https://stackoverflow.com/users/32484/dotnetdev) answers as not an answer.

I have seen ~6 (and growing, probably 10+ now) of them go by in the flag queue in the past hour which seems to be far too many to be random. On the other hand, all of the flagged answers have in fact been not answers and are primarily from 2008.

By vindictive, I mean someone is walking through dotnetdev's answers and effectively auditing them.  Is this acceptable behavior?  The reason I ask is the parallel to serial voting.

Comment: Why do you think this is vindictive? You yourself say: "On the other hand, all of the flagged answers have in fact been not answers.."

Comment: *"Is this acceptable behavior?"* Well, I wouldn't do more than a few of any one user's at a time because I would get bored, but feel free to do mine if you want. As I indicated below, I'm sure I have a few real stinkers left.

Comment: We've had a much worse (read: larger-scale) case of this before, and it does make me uncomfortable, yes. Besides the whole farming-flags thing, this is very similar to serial voting, except it's... I dunno, serial flagging? I'm on the fence on this one.

Comment: Whats wrong with an audit? If someone has posted something terrible I'll often check if its a wider problem. Assuming all the flags are valid this seems like a good thing. The site is presumably cleaned up as a result and unlike serial voting there is oversite to check validity

Comment: @RichardTingle Well, auditing a *user* to the exclusion of others feels a little bit like a violation of the rule to judge the post not the person---because there are plenty of bad post not belonging to the user you have chosen. So I can identify with BoltClock's' unease.

Comment: @Richard Tingle: Someone could "audit" another user's posts (or claim to) in the form of serial upvotes or downvotes too...

Comment: @dmckee meh, I do this all the time. Someone posts a bad question, I check their other questions to see if it's a habit. It's actually a more direct and effective way to clean up content rather than coming across it naturally. If I don't find bad questions then no harm no foul.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I often check their 4--10 most recent posts, too. A global audit, though, is beyond my ambition most of the time.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn True, and if it truly was legitimate up and downvoting on the post (merely attracted by the user, rather than for/against the user) then I'd say fair enough, but we can't know that so its all reversed. On the other hand we can know if a flagging audit is legitimate based on helpful/unhelpful flags

Comment: "*The reason I ask is the parallel to serial voting.*" except that individual votes are not reviewed but individual flags are.

Comment: @Old Checkmark: That is true. I'm totally cool with handling these flags as I come across them for this reason.

Comment: I've been on the receiving end of many of his 700+ questions.  I can see how this happened...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have seen 6 flags on answers of this user, it's not as much, and definitely it's not vindictive flagging. I've read a few answers of this users, and I've found a few that are actually a comments. I've found also the answers to not constructive (according to current criteria) questions, which could be also said to be comments (according to current standards).

As long as someone is not flagging everything, it's OK. If someone sees a poor answer of some user, it's acceptable and appropriate in my opinion to go through the other posts of that user and check them.

It's in our common interest to remove poor questions and answers from the system. No one should feel repressed by such audits. Many experienced users have some poor posts from the beginning of their adventure with SO, and they've even forgotten about them.

Answer (score 12):

I took a look at a few answers and they certainly seem to not be answers, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021558/copy-database-to-another-on-same-server/2021632#2021632), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825738/only-one-instance-of-a-scriptmanager-can-exist-on-a-page/2826764#2826764). Did you look at the actual content of the flagged answers, or did you come here raising the alarms that there must be some funny business going on just because 6 such answers have been flagged? After a very quick sampling of the actual content, this number of flags really does not seem alarming to me. Even though the "answers" are old, they're not answers.

Comment: Many of us who were users in the old days have some not-an-answers hanging around still. I had a couple deleted out from under me in the last year and *I do not mind* because it is leading to a better site. And it's not like the rep matters.

Comment: I did read (and flagged) all of the ones I saw.  I am not questioning the validity of the flags, but the process by which they were raised.

Comment: @tcaswell The process is *irrelevant* if the flags are valid.

Comment: @Servy But you could say the same thing about serial voting.

Comment: @tcaswell The difference is that there's no way of knowing if serial voting is merit based or not.  In the case of flags if there is a very high helpful percentage then we *know* it's merit based.  If we were to see some serial flagging with a very low helpful percentage, in which someone went the route of "flag everything and hope something gets deleted" then that's clear malicious behavior and can be dealt with accordingly.

Answer (score 10):

We all know that certain *users* are the source of certain problems. Consider the 'mod-wsgi troll', for example. So, investigating users to look for problems is as legitimate a janitorial effort as any other janitorial effort.

That raises a question: what's a responsible user to do upon discovery that, in fact, a particular user seems to have left a swath of bad things, previously undetected?

Well, downvoting is right out, due to the serial voting detection mechanisms. For really unwanted stuff, such as spam, flagging one post for a mod and explaining will do.

For a streak of poor answers, then, the 'not an answer' flag seems to be the best we've got -- except for the problem that we're supposed to use the flag *only* for truly incoherent, or comments, or 'thanks' or whatever, not for merely mediocre.

Thus, it seems to me that this question calls for an answer from the team: what would you like us to do? Flagging with a comment like 'this users seems to have left a lot of downvote-worth answers' hardly is usefully actionable.

In the original case at hand, where the answers really aren't answers, I think that flagging them all is just fine.

I just stopped at the brink of another trap here:

1. Start auditing answers
2. See non-answer, vote count 0
3. vote down
4. vote to delete
5. rinse, lather,

uh, oh, serial voting.

I stopped after three.

Comment: "not an answer" isn't for a downvote worthy answer.  If it's really that bad then perhaps "very low quality".  "not an answer" has nothing to do with the quality of the content.  It could be great content that doesn't *attempt* to answer the question and be NAA, or it could be terrible content that does attempt to answer the question, and NAA doesn't apply.

Comment: That is what I wrote in here.